# Correct way to export object in es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to export an my module as an object but exporting it seems  an 'anti pattern' (https://medium.com/@rauschma/note-that-default-exporting-objects-is-usually-an-anti-pattern-if-you-want-to-export-the-cf674423ac38)

So I was wondering what's the correct way to export an object and then use it as

`import utils from "./utils"`
`

`utils.foo()`

Currently I'm doing like so

```
    /** a.js **/
    function foo(){
      //...
    }

    export {
      foo
    }

    /** b.js **/
    import * as utils from "a";

    utils.foo()
```

is it correct like so? Do I maintain the tree-shaking feature?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

If the object you want to import/export only contains some functions (as I assume due to the `Utils` name), you can export the functions separately as follows:

```
export function doStuff1() {}
export function doStuff2() {}
```

And import like this:

```
import {doStuff1, doStuff2} from "./myModule";
```

However, if the object you want to export holds state in addition to methods, you should stick to a simple `export default myObject`. Otherwise, calling the imported methods won't work as intended, since the context of the object is lost.

As an example, the following object should be exported as a whole, since the properties of the object should stay encapsulated. Only importing and calling the `increment` function would not mutate `myObject` since the context of the object cannot be provided (since it's not imported as a whole).

```
const myObject = {
    counter: 0,
    increment: function() {
        this.counter++;
    }
}
export default myObject;
```

Answer (score -1):

es6 native way to do this:

```javascript
// file1.es6
export const myFunc = (param) => {
  doStuff(param)
}

export const otherFunc = ({ param = {} }) => {
  doSomething({ ...param })
}

// file2.es6
import { otherFunc } from './file1.es6'
import * as MyLib from './file1.es6'

MyLib.myfunc(0)
MyLib.otherFunc({ who: 'Repley' })
otherFunc({ var1: { a1: 1 } })
```

And so on.

Comment: isn't this CommonJS syntax?